# Access website localstorage data from a Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bluetooth, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I'm building a packaged app that's meant to interact with a website I wrote to get its localStorage data and send it to other devices using bluetooth.  This seems like it would be easy with an extension, however with an extension I would not have access to chrome's bluetooth API.  I'm not sure this is even possible, but if it is, how would I go about accessing and communicating with the website using the packaged app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you can't. The two local storage repositories are distinct ("sandboxed"), and one can't access the other.

If this website wants to make data available to any other website, or to a Chrome App, it should put it someplace on the server, accessible via a URL, and then the Chrome App can easily access it. But, there's no way to effect such sharing with the data on the client.

Two Chrome Apps can share data locally, because they can access the local file system. However, web apps (HTML/JavaScript loaded from a server) can't access the local file system, only a sandboxed file system.

Comment: After doing some more research, I've discovered that this is possible using a combination of an extension and a packaged app.  It's not nearly as clean as I was hoping, but for the most part, it should work.